# When averaging models, which models need to meet assumptions?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, model-averaging

I have 16 variables and am running all possible models (65,535 total!), then averaging the best models. A model including all variables has normally distributed residuals, but some of the 65,535 individual models will not have normally distributed residuals. Do all of those models have to meet the assumptions? Or just the final model after averaging?

Comment: You can average the models if you want to average the models.  The assumptions for a linear model aren't about whether or not you're *allowed* to construct a model, or even if the model is "good" in some sense.  They are a restriction on being able to perform specific hypothesis tests concerning the regression coefficients.  Are you performing any hypothesis tests?

Comment: Of course, you should probably devise some other method for providing evidence that your model is "good"...

Comment: I do not plan to perform any hypothesis tests. I plan to average the models and calculate the weights of the variables to determine the relative contributions of each predictor to my response variable. So if I do this, then my final model is the only one that needs to be tested against the assumptions? Because in that case I think it will meet all assumptions and be "good" as you say.

Comment: No, a linear model need not meet any of the assumptions to be "good".  The assumptions are all about hypothesis testing.  Meeting the assumptions does not guarantee a "good" model and not meeting the assumptions does not guarantee a "bad" one.

Comment: It is probably worth noting that the average of a bunch of linear models is itself a linear model.  So I'm a bit skeptical that there's any point to this whole exercise.  :)

Comment: Great! So if I'm not hypothesis testing, then the assumptions aren't a deal-breaker, and if I am hypothesis testing then the average model meets the assumptions and I'm good. Now off to figure out what makea a "good" or "bad" model! :-D Thank you Scott

Comment: I don't think the average will be legitimate unless all the variables are orthogonal, which is unlikely.

Comment: @Peter Flom - can you elaborate on that? By orthogonal, do you mean the predictors should not be colinear? Because I have ensured that is the case for this dataset. What do you mean that the average won't be "legitimate" and why do you think it's unlikely the variables are orthogonal?

Comment: @MaeBerlow Colinear would mean exactly related. Orthogonal means not related at all. This rarely happens except in designed experiments.

Comment: @Peter Flom, I have run a VIF to ensure that the variables included in averaging are not colinear. Is that not sufficient?

Comment: No.  For variables to be orthogonal, all correlations between them must be 0 (except for sampling error). This is a different issue. If your variables are even a little related then you are going to need to be careful with model averaging. What if a variable is in one model and not another? Then it will have a higher parameter estimate in the second model.

Comment: If the goal is to determine relative contribution of variables then why not use a boosted regression tree?